# Conversion tracking add to cart button woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a google adwords javascript tag, to the ad to cart button to track conversions.
Where do i need to place it?

Or am I completely beside it and I have to solve it differently? If someone can help me that would be very nice :)

this is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = ***************;
    w.google_conversion_label = "************";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

This is where i want to place it:

> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}

global $product;

if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
 return;
}

echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );

if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

 <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <?php
   /**
    * @since 2.1.0.
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );

   /**
    * @since 3.0.0.
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

   woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
    'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
   ) );

   /**
    * @since 3.0.0.
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
  ?>

  <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

  <?php
   /**
    * @since 2.1.0.
    */
   do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' );
  ?>
 </form>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would track this conversion with javascript jQueryon add to cart button click:

```
$(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function{

    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'category',
        eventAction: 'action',
        eventLabel: 'label',
        eventValue: number
    });
    window.google_trackConversion({
        google_conversion_id: xxxxxxxxx,
        google_conversion_language: "en",
        google_conversion_format: "3",
        google_conversion_color: "ffffff",
        google_conversion_label: "conversion label",
        google_remarketing_only: false
    });
```

});

make sure to add async google analytics.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: sorry the first tag was to check if the page was loaded, the second tag is to check when it is clicked.

Comment: Thank for you help!!!!!!! i realy appreciate it!, Can you please reanswer my quastion with the good tag?

Comment: Just create a new conversion in your analytics and use my code, im not sure what kind of code you are using. I've been using my example all the time :)